# What is the easiest way to make an online high scores table?

Tags: libgdx, android, databases

I made an 2d Android game with using Libgdx library. This game like Flappy Bird. And every user have a highscore. I want to store this highscores respectively to an online database and return the rank of the user in the world ranking.

How to do this? In backend ,which architecture should I use? Is there a tutorial for this?

Comment: Are you sure that the easiest way is a good idea? Consider how many highscore tables there are out there which are full of impossible scores submitted by hacking the submission.

Answer (score -1):

First you need a web site which gives you cgi access.  I don't think
any of the "free" sites will do that, but a minimal web server is
pretty cheap; or perhaps you can find a friendly site to host your
database and associated scripts.

Second, design a simple web interface to view and update the high
scores table, using a mysql database and cgi scripts written in
perl, php, python, or whatever back end you want.  The public interface
to add new high scores need not be left up permanantly, it's just for
development.

Third, access those same scripts, or simple variants, from your
android game using https requests.

And as Pete Taylor says, you must add some authentication to prevent the
transactions being hacked.  The minimal version of this would be to
add a checksum of all the relevant data elements, plus the device id,
plus some secret keystring.

If you look around, you will probably find open sources that
have already done all that for you, except of course adding
the https access to your app.

Comment: I think this is bad advice, you should be looking to use a pre-rolled solution who will host your scores not going through the difficulty of creating your own. Something like Google Play leaderboards, for example.

Comment: What are you thinking about FireBase?

Comment: On android, you can let Google host your high scores table on their servers through [Google Play Games Services](https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/scores/list). That way you don't need an own website or database. Unfortunately I never used it, so I do not feel qualified to write a complete answer.

Comment: @JackAidley Although the answer could use some improvement, the question asks how can someone **make** something like this. Sure Google Play leaderboards are available, but for all we know, the OP might just want to experiment with different technologies for the sake of learning.

Comment: @TomTsagk I think you're reading too much into the word 'make'. It seems to me the OP just wants to know how to add leaderboards, and the "easiest way" in the title would seem to support that interpretation. In any case, I didn't downvote because it's a valid approach, I just think it's the wrong one.